Detox can't find ActivityIndicator by testID in React Native
I'm running Detox tests for a React Native screen, and I'm encountering an issue where Detox can't seem to access the ActivityIndicator component by its testID. The ActivityIndicator is displayed while data is being fetched, and it should disappear once the data is loaded, but the test fails to detect the loader.
it('should display loader while data is loading', async () => {
      const sampleScreen = element(by.id('sample-screen'));
      await waitFor(sampleScreen).toBeVisible().withTimeout(5000);

      const loadingIndicator = element(by.id('loading-indicator'));
      await expect(loadingIndicator).toBeVisible(); // This fails
    });

{isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator testID='loading-indicator' size='large' />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          testID='data-list'
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <View>{item.name}</View>}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      )}

I have tried adding below lines for resource Idling:
 await device.disableSynchronization(); 
 await device.enableSynchronization();

https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/troubleshooting/synchronization/

You should put await device.disableSynchronization(); before action that leads to Sync issue

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Find help with formatting your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . Consider taking the [tour].
